# Nginx maintenance mode static assets (js, css, png)

Tags: nginx, google-chrome-devtools, devops, maintenance-mode

I have 2 npm scripts. One build **maintenance** folder. Second one deletes maintenance folder and build **dist** folder. My goal is when maintenance folder exists serve its content and redirects every request to its index.html. These folders structure is ./index.html, ./1.png, ./2.png, ./assets/bundle.js, ./assets/bundle.css, ./assets/3.png, ./assets/font.woff2. My current nginx config:

```
server { 
        listen 443 ssl http2; 
        server_name my-site.com; 
 
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key; 
 
        root /home/user1/site/dist/; 
 
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; 
  
        error_page 401 /; 
 
        # MAINTENANCE MODE 
        error_page 503 @maintenance; 
 
        if (-f /home/user1/site/maintenance/index.html) { 
                return 503; 
        } 
 
        location @maintenance { 
                root /home/user1/site/maintenance; 
                if (!-f $request_filename) { 
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break; 
                } 
                return 200; 
        } 
        
        # Normal mode
 
        location / { 
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
        } 
 
        # other backend proxy_pass locations
}
```

There is a 503 status for every file in Chrome DevTools but html is visible and assets are not.
Config above is what i have come to after day of research. I have a feeling i need to fix one or two strings to make it work, but i'm newbie in nginx.